# Sum up to N highest-value out of a series?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet where each row is a set of numerical competition scores. Each row can be thought of as a single competitor in the overall competition, and each column is a competition event. Nothing truly unusual there.

Now, I want to take **the sum of the *N* highest value scores** out of each row, such that:

- If less than or equal to *N* scores are provided, sum all listed scores
- If more than *N* scores are provided, sum the *N* highest out of the series

How to do that?

In my particular case, *N* = 5, but I'm hoping that a generic solution exists.

I'd prefer not using a macro for this, but am willing to explore that avenue if it can't be done with a simple formula.

Comment: Would a VBA macro work for you?

Comment: @BradPatton Do VBA macros work in LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have LibreOffice that is why I was asking you.

Comment: @BradPatton I probably could put together a macro that works in LOC, but as I said in the question, I'd prefer a non-macro-based solution. The logic of a macro wouldn't be very hard to get right, though perhaps the "trivial" approach would be less than perfect performance-wise (then again, I wouldn't do anything performance-critical in a macro anyway).

Comment: I don't know any Excel functions that would directly solve what you are trying to do. I could probably write a macro that would do it. I think that is your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `LARGE` function.

```
=LARGE(Range;1)+LARGE(Range;2)+…+LARGE(Range;N)
```

or

```
=SUM(LARGE(Range;1); LARGE(Range;2); …; LARGE(Range;N))
```

Note that, in some locales, function parameters must be separated by commas rather than semicolons.

Comment: This is perfect; almost exactly what I was hoping for! The only downside is that it errors out if there is no Nth largest value, but a set of IF() and COUNT() did the trick with that.

Comment: This is cumbersome if _N_ is large.  If _N_ is a fixed value (known when you build the spreadsheet), e.g., 5, the `SUM` form can be simplified to `SUM(LARGE(Range;{1,2,3,4,5}))`.  Press (Ctrl)+(Shift)+(Enter) to create an array formula.  Also, either way, this requires _rewriting_ the formula if _N_ changes.

Answer (score 2):

OK, if your data numeric data are in rows on `Sheet1`, then enter your *N* value into `Sheet2!N1`, and enter

```
=SUM(LARGE(Sheet1!1:1, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MIN(COUNT(Sheet1!1:1),N$1)))))
```

into `Sheet2!A1`.  (If your data are only in, for example, Columns `G` through `Z`, change `Sheet1!1:1` to `Sheet1!G1:Z1`.)  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to create an array formula.  Drag down as many rows as you need, and you should be done.  (Note that, in `Sheet2!A17`, for example, `Sheet1!1:1` will have automatically changed to `Sheet1!17:17`, i.e., the 17th row of `Sheet1`, because the row number is relative –– not preceded by `$`.)

#### Explanation:

- `COUNT(Sheet1!1:1)` is the number of numbers (scores) in the referenced row (which,
  as indicated above, might be Row `1`, Row `17`, or whatever row you’re looking at on `Sheet2`). 
  I do this because you said, “not all competitors take part in each event”;
  I assume that the non-participations are blank, or perhaps a non-numeric string.
- `N$1` is your specified *N* value; the number of scores you want to add.
- `MIN()` is, of course, minimum.  If *N* is 5, and a competitor was in only three events, we want to add all three.  If a competitor was in seven events, we want to sum the highest five.
- `&` is the string concatenation operator in Excel (and, from what I’ve heard, Libre Office Calc is very similar to Excel), so, if the number of scores (`MIN(…)`) that we’re adding is, say, 5, then `"1:"&MIN(…)` becomes the string value `"1:5"`.
- `INDIRECT("1:5")` is the region comprising Row `1` through Row `5`, and
- `ROW()` of that is the array `{1,2,3,4,5}`.
  This is a trick for creating an array value that’s specified by run-time data.
- `LARGE(Sheet1!1:1, {1,2,3,4,5})` is the array `{ LARGE(Sheet1!1:1,1), LARGE(Sheet1!1:1,2),
  LARGE(Sheet1!1:1,3), LARGE(Sheet1!1:1,4), LARGE(Sheet1!1:1,5) }`,
  which is the largest (highest) score in the range, the second largest, …, and so on,
  down to the 5th.

I have assumed that you’re in a locale that uses commas for separators. 
If you’re in the land of semicolons, do as the semicolons do.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by building the scores as a table then keep the table sorted by the score. Then you can look at only the first n columns...

If you need to change n "on the fly" you can do indirect referencing of the cells based on a value that you set.

Comment: This falls apart because each competitor can have wildly differing scores in each event, and not all competitors take part in each event (in fact, I'd be surprised if any one has a score from each event!). It's difficult to really explain in detail without going into specifics that are not relevant to the question, but there are good reasons for this. I do not need to change the value of *n* on the fly in any way, however.

Comment: then your question seems a little off... If you want to do this on a column by column basis you could move to pivot tables for each column. No matter what you do, there is going to be a lot of extra data to be carried. If each event had a competitor and a score - put each on a separate sheet to make it easier. There is something to be gained by filtering but it only works per-column - see http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUBTOTAL_function for some ideas

Comment: Have you considered switching to a database?

Comment: *"Have you considered switching to a database?"* Going with a database solution just to be able to sum a few columns seems a little excessive. Yes, this would be relatively trivial to solve with SQL, but math is pretty much what spreadsheets are all about, and surely it can't be *that* unusual to want to sum the highest numbers in a series.